# linking two objects, value to value, and filling in any missing values in the sequence

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I am trying to merge two objects into 1 Array, and they must be linked by their values. The objects are 'Days' and 'Count' which is the count of the number of events that happen on a day.

**Example Data**

```
{"Day":[3,8,9,17,18,21,25,27,30,31],
"Count":[1,3,1,1,1,4,2,2,2,1]}
```

I can do that with this function:

```
var data = {{loanDates.data}}; // this query has two objects, 'Day' and 'Count' which is the sum of the number of events that has happened on each day.

return data.Day.map(function(day, key){
  var count = test.Count[key];
      return {
        day,count
      }
    });
```

**result**

```
[{"day":3,"count":1},
{"day":8,"count":3},
{"day":9,"count":1},
{"day":17,"count":1},
{"day":18,"count":1},
{"day":21,"count":4},
{"day":25,"count":2},
{"day":27,"count":2},
{"day":30,"count":2},
{"day":31,"count":1}]
```

This returns the correct things, however i want all the days of the month. So for instance say the 10th day of the month doesn't exist in the object, i need a 10th day created and its count set to 0.

**Outcome required**

```
[{"day":1,"count":0},
{"day":2,"count":0},
{"day":3,"count":1},
{"day":4,"count":0},
{"day":5,"count":0},
{"day":6,"count":0},
{"day":7,"count":0},
{"day":8,"count":3},
{"day":9,"count":1},
{"day":10,"count":0},
{..................},
{"day":31,"count":0},]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd make an object mapping each Day to its Count from the input data, then give it keys 1-31 if it doesn't have them already. Afterwards, you can use `Object.entries` to map each entry to a value in the array:

```js
const input = {
  "Day":[3,8,9,17,18,21,25,27,30,31],
  "Count":[1,3,1,1,1,4,2,2,2,1]
};
const countsByDay = {};
input.Day.forEach((day, i) => {
  countsByDay[day] = input.Count[i];
});
for (let i = 0; i <= 31; i++) {
  countsByDay[i] = countsByDay[i] || 0;
}
const output = Object.entries(countsByDay).map(
  ([day, count]) => ({ day, count })
);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. How can i get the output to be just an array of the count eg: output = [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,3,1,0........,0,1]

Comment: Take the object's values. `Object.values(countsByDay)`

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array.from()` to generate an array of days with `count: 0`, spread to an array, and override with the array of days that has count values:

```js
const data = {
  "Day":[3,8,9,17,18,21,25,27,30,31],
  "Count":[1,3,1,1,1,4,2,2,2,1]
}

const result = [
  ...Array.from({ length: 31 }, (_, i) => ({ day: i + 1, count: 0 })),
  ...data.Day.map((day, i) => ({ day, count: data.Count[i] }))
]

console.log(result)
```